# Xml Schema Pattern At The Beginning Of A String

Tags: regex, xml, schema

I am new to XML Schema and to RegEx.

I want to define a pattern that matches the following structure:

```
<fantastic>:item.attribute</fantastic>
```

as well as:

```
<fantastic>:item.attribute,:item.attribute,:item.attribute</fantastic>
```

I would like to have pairs of items and attributes. If there is more than one pair, the pairs should be seperated by a comma. So I would like to tell the parser the following:

*'If the pattern starts at the beginning of a string no comma is put before it. Else a comma needs to be put before the (repeated) string.'*

The pattern for the item and the attribute is much more complicated. But it works with the exception of the comma seperation between the pairs.

I have done some research and found out that ^ is used to tell the parser that the previous character has to be at the beginning of a string.

But I could not use it in **XML Schema *Pattern***. Does it exist in XML anyway?

How would you write this?

Kind regards

Comment: You should never need Regex to read XML, there are a number of mature XML parsing technologies available that allow easy consumption of XML, as long as it is well formed.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just wanted to point out, that I am not so familliar with pattern and with regEx which has a lot of analogies.